# Database fetch class

Tags: php, object-oriented, classes, pdo

The active column in the database only contains a boolean. The country column contains ISO 3166 A2 codes (2 char). Do you have any advice on improving this class?

```
<?php
class WebShops {
    private $database;

    public function __construct() {
            $this->database = new Database();
    }

    public function fetchAll() {
            $this->database->query("SELECT * FROM web_shops");
            return $this->database->fetchAll();
    }

    public function fetchActive($option) {
            $this->database->query("SELECT * FROM web_shops WHERE active = :option");
            $this->database->bind(':option', $option);
            return $this->database->fetchAll();
    }

    public function fetchCountry($country) {
            $this->database->query("SELECT * FROM web_shops WHERE country = :country");
            $this->database->bind(':country', $country);
            return $this->database->fetchAll();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could validate `$option` and `$country` before you put them in a query. One needs to be true or false, and the other should be two letters A-Z. You need some kind of error handling for that.

For the rest: This is such a simple class, and the context is missing, what would you want us to say?

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @KIKO Sotfware that becuase the question lacks context, we cannot provide an extensive review. But there is one thing which caught my eye.

You ahould utilize **dependency injection** in your constructor. By hard coding your database class into the constructor you make it hard to swap the implementation if a another one is required in the future or you want to write a *test*.

I would build a generic interface which implements the different method the class uses.

```
interface GenericDatabaseInterface {

    public function query($sql);
    public function bind($key, $value);
    public function fetchAll();

}
```

Your database class should implement this interface. You would then type-hint this interface in your constructors argument list. If you in the future requires another implementation the new class should also implement the interface.

```
public function __construct(GenericDatabaseInterface $database) {

    $this->database = $database;

}
```

Hope this can guide you a little, happy coding!